# Destructure object and reassign to different variable name in one go

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax

I have an object:

```
let obj = {
  "t":
    {
      "en": {
        "head" :"hello",
        "sub"  : "this is great"
      }
    }
  "link": {}
}
```

and I'm destructuring it:

```
{ t: { en }}
```

is it possible to reassign `t` to `en` in the same destructuring statement?

So I want the object assigned to `en` in the variable `t` not in `en`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're destructuring an object, you can specify `propname: variablename` to assign the property to a variable with a different name. Putting just the property name without a variable is equivalent to `propname: propname`, to use the same name for the variable and property, but you don't need to use that shortcut.

So you can do it like this:

```js
let obj = {
  "t":
    {
      "en": {
        "head" :"hello",
        "sub"  : "this is great"
      }
    }
}

let { t: { en: t } } = obj;
console.log(t);
```

The first `t:` is just a property name, it specifies that the value is an object which needs to be destructured as well. In that structure, we use the `propname: variablename` syntax, so the `en` property is assigned to the `t` variable.

In a function definition this would look like:

```js
const Home = ({ t: { en: t }, link}) => console.log(t);

let obj = {
  "t":
    {
      "en": {
        "head" :"hello",
        "sub"  : "this is great"
      }
    }
};
Home(obj);
```

Note that there's no actual relationship between the two uses of `t`. The variable can actually be anything, e.g.

```
const Home = ({ t: { en: blah }, link}) => console.log(blah);
```

Comment: But I don't have access to obj where I want to reassign. Imagine I have value of `t` available and I want to reassign value of `en` to `t`. How to do this without having `obj`

Comment: To be more precise it looks like this `const Home = ({ t, link }) => (...)`, and I want t to be value of `en`

Comment: `const Home = ({ t: {en : t}, link}) => (...)`

Comment: I think you may have been confusing yourself by trying to use the same variable as the top-level property name.

Comment: Nah not in this case. This was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible to reassign `t`, because `t` is a `const`. If `t` *weren't* a `const`, then yes, it would be possible to reassign it:

```js
let t = {
  "en":
    {
      "head": "hello",
      "sub" : "this is great"
    }
};

({ en: t } = t);
console.log(t);
```

Note that

```
{ t: <something>
```

would only be done with destructuring if `t` were a *property* of the parent object - but here, `t` is a standalone variable, not a property so instead, start with

```
{ en: <something>
```

with `t` on the *right-hand* side.

If `t` actually *is* a property of the parent object, then you can do the same sort of thing:

```js
let obj = {
  "t":
    {
      "en": {
        "head" :"hello",
        "sub"  : "this is great"
      }
    },
  "link": {}
};
const { t: { en: t } } = obj;
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Sorry you are right, I missed that in my initial question. `t` is a property of an object. I will amend this. How does this apply now?

Comment: To be more precise it looks like this `const Home = ({ t, link }) => (...)`, and I want t to be value of `en`

Comment: See edit, `const { t: { en: t } } = obj;` given the code in the question

Comment: I don't know the variable name of obj

Comment: Huh? If you don't know the name of the variable, how would you ever reference it in the first place? Dynamic variable names are quite a code smell

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one line in the following manner:

```js
let obj = {
  "t":
    {
      "en": {
        "head" :"hello",
        "sub"  : "this is great"
      }
    }
}

// here we are destructuring en but declaring 
// it as a variable which is called t
let { en: t } =  obj.t;

console.log(t)
```

We can choose an alias in a destructuring assignment using a colon.

Comment: I'm not getting it to work. Let me show you the current way I implement it:
`const Home = ({ t: { en }, link }) => ()`, when I do `const Home = ({ { en: t } = t, link }) => ()` it doesn't work